# Setting data with an event listener and the FormEvent::PRE_SET_DATA Event in Symfony2

Tags: forms, symfony, entity, formbuilder

I'm attempting to modify some data in a form based on other data that is in the form. From [the docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/form/form_events.html):

> The FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA event is dispatched at the beginning of the Form::setData() method. It can be used to:
>
> - **Modify the data given during pre-population**
> - Modify a form depending on the pre-populated data (adding or removing fields dynamically).

This bolded line made me believe it should be possible to do something like the following in my `buildForm` function:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->addEventListener(\Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA,
        function(\Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvent $event) use ($options) {
            if ($options['default_to_nickname']) {
                $securityContext = $this->container->get('security.context');
                $nickname = null;
                if ($securityContext->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY')) {
                    $user = $securityContext->getToken()->getUser();
                    $nickname = $user->getNickName();
                    if (isset($nickname))
                    {
                        $options['data'] = $nickname;
                        //$event->setData($nickname); //this doesn't work either
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    );
}
```

However, neither `options['data'] = $nickname;` nor `$event->setData($nickname);` result in the form being populated with the correct data. I can see that the data is being set in the FormEvent object when I call `$event->setData($nickname);`, but when the form is actually rendered, the data was not set. Am I expecting the wrong thing? I've looked into if something else might be modifying it after this, and there isn't. Any help would be very welcome!

Answer (score 2):

You have to call `$event->getForm()->get('your_property')->setData($nickname)`. Replace `get()` method by `add($property, $type, ['data' => $nickname])` if the property doesn't exist yet.

See : http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html#adding-an-event-subscriber-to-a-form-class

Comment: Thanks for the reply! This is what I thought at first too, but you get an error if you do this. See: [link](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/form/form_events.html): `"During FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, Form::setData() is locked and will throw an exception if used. If you wish to modify data, you should use FormEvent::setData() instead."` Doing what you suggest, you get the following error: `"A cycle was detected. Listeners to the PRE_SET_DATA event must not call setData(). You should call setData() on the FormEvent object instead."` Any idea how to work with this?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read the catched event. The `$event->setData()` should expect for an array, indexed by your properties name.

Comment: Is that true? In my case at least, I got errors where symfony was complaining because I was trying to cast an array to a string. Calling `setData()` with a string only, however, actually does work (stepping through it, it puts it in an array for me, which is confusing when looking at the fact that passing in an array gave errors). So it looks like `$event->setData($nickname)` is correct! It turns out something was modifying this field way after the fact. I think I might delete this question as I'm not sure how much it will help other people

Comment: Your answer helped me. Thanks!